# What is the average velocity of the motorcycle?

Tags: calculus, classical-mechanics

The position of a person riding in a motorcycle race is give by $s(t)=4t^2+3t$, where $t$ measures time in seconds since the race began, and position is measured in feet beyond the starting line.  Determine the average velocity of the motorcycle rider on the interval $[1,4]$.  Include units in your answer.

My answer that I got is $20.33$ m/sec but a friend is getting a different answer.

Comment: Please show your steps so that we can help spot where you may have made a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are wrong

correct answer is 23

average velocity = change in displacement /time taken

```
             = (s(t=4)-s(t=1))/4-1

             = (76 - 7) / 3

             = 23
```

Comment: wouldn't you have:

s(t)= 4(4)^2-3(1) / 4-1?

Comment: it will be {4(4)^2 + 3(4)} - {4(1)^2 + 3(1)}

Comment: what did you write , could you just give an explanation to it

Comment: I was using the equation for average rate of change:  f(x^2)-f(x1)/x2-x1

Comment: where did you find this formula

Comment: in my calc book

Comment: I am afraid that must be {f(x2) -f(x1)}/x2-x2

Comment: I believe what @Matt is saying is that for a given function $f(x)$, it's average rate of change from $x_1$ to $x_2$ is given by $\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}$

Comment: @Mufasa But he has squared x ^2 and even I have used the same formula in my answer

Comment: @Matt - and this is exactly what DSinghvi has done above. DSinghvi - I believe Matt may have made a typing error?

Comment: i squared it because of the equation 4t^2+3t

Comment: that is how I got 4(4)^2+3(1)/ 4-1

Comment: @Matt - then you have not understood this topic correctly

Comment: I think you should read article about notation regarding functions

Comment: @Matt - you find this useful: http://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/tutorials/frames2_1.html

Comment: Thank you both very much for your help!

Comment: @Matt - you're welcome :)